# Angular 2 directive not invoked

Tags: angular

The goal of my task is to make url-s in div text clickable. I am starting learning Angular 2. I created a directive and trying to use linkifyjs module.

**The directive:**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import linkifyStr from 'linkifyjs/string';

@Directive({selector: '[linkify]'})
export class LinkifyDirective {

  constructor(private el?: ElementRef) {
        console.log('CHECKPOINT1'); //THIS IS NOT PRESENT IN CONSOLE
        this.el.nativeElement.textContent = 'asd'; //THE TEXT IS DIFFERENT ON THE PAGE AFTER RENDERING, so this constructor is not even invoked.. ?
        this.el.nativeElement.textContent = this.transform(this.el.nativeElement.textContent);
  }

  private transform(str: string): string {
      return str ? linkifyStr(str, {target: '_system'}) : str;
  }
}
```

**The app.module.ts**

```
import { LinkifyDirective } from './directives/linkify.directive';

@NgModule({   declarations: [
    AppComponent, LinkifyDirective   ],   exports: [
    AppComponent, LinkifyDirective ],
```

**The existing component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-event',
  templateUrl: 'event.template.html',
  styleUrls: ['event.style.scss']
})

export class EventComponent implements OnInit {
```

There is no linkify lines here.

**The **event.template.html** with linkify directive:**

```
 <div class="text-wrap text-area-description" linkify name="description">
                                      {{event.description }}</div>
```

**The package.json:**

```
"dependencies": {
...
"linkifyjs": "^2.1.5",
....
```

**The rendered content:**

```
<div _ngcontent-c1="" class="text-wrap text-area-description" linkify="" name="description">
              Some sample text with address https://myip.com</div>
```

The problem here is that the linkify directive is not invoked or something like that. There is no CHECKPOINT1 log and the text is not converted to be clickable although it has url inside.

> Some sample text with address https://myip.com

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that your EventComponent is not declared in your AppModule. If you have it declared in a separate module, the linkifyDirective needs to either be declared in THAT module, or in a module that is imported there.

Comment: Thanks, the CHECKPOINT1 is present now :)

Comment: Still Ihave some issue - in constructor innerText of div is empty. OnInit method in my directive successfully linkifies only static part of div: "Sample url: http://google.com {{event.description }}" so event.description remains unclickable, but http://google.com is clickable.

Comment: Try moving the linkify logic to ngAfterViewInit (if it will be static content) or ngAfterViewChecked if the content will be dynamic and can change